# "httpd.exe: Could not open configuration file C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: apache, configuration

I got the above error when I ran httpd.exe on my cmd.

Prior to this I encountered an error:
"AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::9b6a:765:61b7:2762. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message"

I did chatgpt and made changes in the "httpd.conf" text file inside "confg" folder.
I changed ServerName example.www.com:80 (i don't remeber if this was it) to -> ServerName 127.0.0.1:80.

what happened is httpd.conf changed to httpd only. Then I renamed it and got this error.

can somebody tell me how to solve this problem?
(I am a complete beginner)